# Nested loops in brainfuck

Tags: c, loops, nested, interpreter, brainfuck

I have written a brainfuck interpreter using C. This program has implementation of linked list which stores the brainfuck instructions and has the implementation of stack which stores '[' instruction from brainfuck.

I think my program doesn't support nested loops in every case. This is ridiculous, but this brainfuck program works correctly with my interpter and prints "Hello World!" to stdout:

```
++++++++[>++++[>++>+++>+++>+<<<<-]>+>+>->>+[<]<-]>>.>---.+++++++..+++.>>.<-.<.+++.------.--------.>>+.>++.
```

But this program doesn't work correctly and prints memory error to stdout:

```
+[-[<<[+[--->]-[<<<]]]>>>-]>-.---.>..>.<<<<-.<+.>>>>>.>.<<.<-.
```

These two examples work correct with an online interpter - https://copy.sh/brainfuck/.

I try to solve this problem, but I spent a lot of time on it and I failed so I am asking you to help me out.

This is the code of my interpreter:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sysexits.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define EX_SUCCESS 0

#define str1_is_less_than_str2 (strcmp("bf", file_extension) < 0)
#define str2_is_less_than_str1 (strcmp("bf", file_extension) > 0)

#define MEMSIZE 30000
#define NUMBER_OF_BF_INSTRUCTIONS 8

#define FIRST_ELEMENT_NOT_EXISTS (*head_ptr == NULL)

struct bf_instruction_node {
    int bf_instruction;
    struct bf_instruction_node *next_element;
};

struct stack_node {
    struct bf_instruction_node *bf_instr_ptr;
    struct stack_node *link;
};

void inc_ptr(int **values_ptr) { ++(*values_ptr); }
void dec_ptr(int **values_ptr) { --(*values_ptr); }
void inc_value(int *values_ptr) { ++(*values_ptr); }
void dec_value(int *values_ptr) { --(*values_ptr); }
void print_value(int *values_ptr) { putchar(*values_ptr); }
void input_value(int *values_ptr) { *values_ptr = getchar(); }

void push(struct stack_node **esp_ptr, struct bf_instruction_node *current_instr_ptr) {
    struct stack_node *new_element_on_the_stack;
    new_element_on_the_stack = (struct stack_node *)malloc(sizeof(struct stack_node));
    new_element_on_the_stack->bf_instr_ptr = current_instr_ptr;
    new_element_on_the_stack->link = *esp_ptr;
    *esp_ptr = new_element_on_the_stack;
}

void pop(struct stack_node **esp_ptr) {
    struct stack_node *tmp;
    tmp = *esp_ptr;
    *esp_ptr = (*esp_ptr)->link;
    free(tmp);
}

void start_loop(int *values_ptr, struct stack_node **esp_ptr, struct bf_instruction_node *current_instr_ptr) {
    push(esp_ptr, current_instr_ptr);
}

void end_loop(int *values_ptr, struct bf_instruction_node **current_instr_ptr, struct stack_node **esp_ptr) {
    if( *values_ptr != 0  ) {
        if( *values_ptr < 0 )
            *values_ptr = 255;
        if( *values_ptr > 255 )
            *values_ptr = 0;

        *current_instr_ptr = (*esp_ptr)->bf_instr_ptr;
        // *current_instr_ptr = (*current_instr_ptr)->next_element;
    } else  {
        pop(esp_ptr);
    }
}

void execute_instructions(int **values_ptr, struct bf_instruction_node *head_ptr, struct bf_instruction_node **current_instr_ptr) {
    struct stack_node *esp_ptr = NULL;

    char brainfuck_instruction;
    *current_instr_ptr = head_ptr;

    while( *current_instr_ptr != NULL ) {
        brainfuck_instruction = (*current_instr_ptr)->bf_instruction;

        switch( brainfuck_instruction ) {
            case '>': inc_ptr(values_ptr);                                  break;
            case '<': dec_ptr(values_ptr);                                  break;
            case '+': inc_value(*values_ptr);                               break;
            case '-': dec_value(*values_ptr);                               break;
            case '.': print_value(*values_ptr);                             break;
            case ',': input_value(*values_ptr);                             break;
            case '[': start_loop(*values_ptr, &esp_ptr, *current_instr_ptr);break;
            case ']': end_loop(*values_ptr, current_instr_ptr, &esp_ptr);   break;
        }

        *current_instr_ptr = (*current_instr_ptr)->next_element;
    }
}

struct bf_instruction_node *create_new_element(struct bf_instruction_node **head_ptr, struct bf_instruction_node **current_instr_ptr, int char_from_file) { 
    struct bf_instruction_node *new_element;
    *current_instr_ptr = *head_ptr;

    while( (*current_instr_ptr)->next_element != NULL )
        *current_instr_ptr = (*current_instr_ptr)->next_element;

    new_element = (struct bf_instruction_node *)malloc(sizeof(struct bf_instruction_node));

    return new_element;
}

void add_instruction_to_the_list(struct bf_instruction_node **head_ptr, struct bf_instruction_node **current_instr_ptr, int char_from_file) {
    if( FIRST_ELEMENT_NOT_EXISTS ) {
        *head_ptr = (struct bf_instruction_node *)malloc(sizeof(struct bf_instruction_node));

        if( *head_ptr == NULL ) {
            perror("Memory allocation failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else {
            (*head_ptr)->bf_instruction = char_from_file;
            (*head_ptr)->next_element = NULL;
            *current_instr_ptr = *head_ptr;
        }
    } else {
        struct bf_instruction_node *new_element = create_new_element(head_ptr, current_instr_ptr, char_from_file);

        if( new_element == NULL ) {
            perror("Memory allocation failed.");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else {
            new_element->bf_instruction = char_from_file;
            new_element->next_element = NULL;
            (*current_instr_ptr)->next_element = new_element;
            *current_instr_ptr = new_element;
        }
    }
}

void print_instructions(struct bf_instruction_node *head_ptr, struct bf_instruction_node **current_instr_ptr) {
    *current_instr_ptr = head_ptr;

    while( *current_instr_ptr != NULL ) {
        printf("%c", (*current_instr_ptr)->bf_instruction);
        *current_instr_ptr = (*current_instr_ptr)->next_element;
    }
}

void clear_the_memory(struct bf_instruction_node *head_ptr, struct bf_instruction_node **current_instr_ptr) {
    struct bf_instruction_node *earlier_element;

    *current_instr_ptr = head_ptr;

    while( (*current_instr_ptr) != NULL ) {
        earlier_element = *current_instr_ptr;
        *current_instr_ptr = (*current_instr_ptr)->next_element;
        free(earlier_element);
    }

    puts("Memory is cleared.");
}

const char *is_bf_instruction(int char_from_file) {
    const char bf_alphabet[NUMBER_OF_BF_INSTRUCTIONS] = {'>', '<', '+', '-', ',', '.', '[', ']'};
    return memchr(bf_alphabet, char_from_file, sizeof(bf_alphabet));
}

const char *get_file_extension(const char *filename) {
    const char *dot = strchr(filename, '.');

    if( dot == NULL )
        return NULL;

    const char *file_extension = dot + 1;
    return file_extension;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if( argc < 2 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "File not specified.\n");
        puts("usage: ./bf_interpreter <filename.bf>");
        return EX_USAGE;
    }

    const char *filename = argv[1];
    const char *file_extension = get_file_extension(filename);

    if( file_extension == NULL || str1_is_less_than_str2 || str2_is_less_than_str1 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Incorrect file extension.\n");
        puts("usage: ./bf_interpreter <filename.bf>");
        return EX_DATAERR;
    }

    FILE *file_with_bf_code = fopen(filename, "r");

    if( file_with_bf_code == NULL ) {
        perror(filename);
        return EX_NOINPUT;
    }

    int values[MEMSIZE] = {0}, *values_ptr = values;
    int char_from_file;

    struct bf_instruction_node *head_ptr = NULL, *current_instr_ptr;

    while( (char_from_file = fgetc(file_with_bf_code)) != EOF ) {
        if( is_bf_instruction(char_from_file) != NULL )
            add_instruction_to_the_list(&head_ptr, &current_instr_ptr, char_from_file);
    }

    execute_instructions(&values_ptr, head_ptr, &current_instr_ptr);
    clear_the_memory(head_ptr, &current_instr_ptr);

    return EX_SUCCESS;
}
```

I think that this function produce the errors with the *memory violation*:

```
void end_loop(int *values_ptr, struct bf_instruction_node **current_instr_ptr, struct stack_node **esp_ptr) {
    if( *values_ptr != 0  ) {
        if( *values_ptr < 0 )
            *values_ptr = 255;
        if( *values_ptr > 255 )
            *values_ptr = 0;

        *current_instr_ptr = (*esp_ptr)->bf_instr_ptr;
        // *current_instr_ptr = (*current_instr_ptr)->next_element;
    } else {
        pop(esp_ptr);
    }
}
```

I hope that someone can help me with this. Cheers and thank you in advance!

Comment: You are asking us to debug a complete program? Please provide a [mcve] and a precise problem statement with expected and actual output.

Comment: A simple way to handle nested loops is *recursion*.

Comment: Can I show you the functions that produce the problem (I think) below the whole code of the program? This is interpreter so the whole code is necessary to show that this program really works incorrectly.

Comment: Hmmm, I agree that you may have a valid point, but at least try to find the shortest and simplest possible input that fails this way.

Comment: With a little luck you don't need to use all operators, and thus you can skip a few functions.

Comment: And don't guess where the problem is. Use a debugger and find out.

Answer (score 2):

You need to debug.

I tried your code. Got different results depending on if I used optimization or not. This is a good indication of *undefined behavior*. With optimization `-O3` and `-O2` I got this segfault:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
execute_instructions (values_ptr=0x7ffffffe0ca8, head_ptr=<optimized out>, current_instr_ptr=0x7ffffffe0cb8) at bf.c:83
83              case ']': end_loop(*values_ptr, current_instr_ptr, &esp_ptr);   break;
```

Using `-O1` gave:

```
$ ./a.out fil.bf 
��Memory is cleared.
```

No optimization just seemed to get stuck in an endless loop. I let it run for about 5 seconds, but nothing happened.

Furthermore, your code produces two warnings:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 -pedantic bf.c
bf.c: In function ‘start_loop’:
bf.c:48:22: warning: unused parameter ‘values_ptr’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 void start_loop(int *values_ptr, struct stack_node **esp_ptr, struct bf_instruction_node *current_instr_ptr) {
                      ^~~~~~~~~~
bf.c: In function ‘create_new_element’:
bf.c:90:139: warning: unused parameter ‘char_from_file’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 struct bf_instruction_node *create_new_element(struct bf_instruction_node **head_ptr, struct bf_instruction_node **current_instr_ptr, int char_from_file) {
                                                                                                                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know that I can debug the code with optimizations. This is very helpful stuff for me. But I throw the brainfuck code into Brainfuck Visualizer and now I know that I need to get balance of the loops. This thought can be the solution.

Comment: You can, but it can be harder.

Comment: Here is a link with tips on how to debug https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I want to thank you again @klutt, because one of the method in that link helped me to debug my program and finally it all works! "Print it" is a magic trick, but I didn't appreciate this till today.

Comment: @KamilSzpakowski Glad to hear it. Always fun to help people learn how to debug.

Answer (score 1):

for whatever it worth (if this issue is still relevant) - I think the problem is that you did not correctly implement start_loop.
at the beginning of the loop (the '[' char) - if the current location's content is 0 - the loop is skipped altogether.

In your code - you simply continue the code execution, regardless of the current cell content, which is a mistake.

In addition - I'm not sure that your loop_end implementation is correct. You don't need to tamper with the cell content during loop check. Simply check the content. Zero - exit loop. Non zero - go back to the corresponding loop_start.